# Problem with Gearman: GEARMAN_COULD_NOT_CONNECT

Tags: php, unix, debian, gearman

I've installed gearman using "apt-get install gearman-server" and than build the PHP PECL.

If i try the worker:

> $ gearman -w -f wc -- wc -l

It starts waiting. right.

But if i try to start a job (as descriped in the tutorial)

> $ gearman -f wc < /etc/passwd

it says:

> gearman: gearman_client_run_tasks : flush(GEARMAN_COULD_NOT_CONNECT)
>   127.0.0.1:4730 -> libgearman/connection.cc:480

And if i try the PHP str_rev demo descriped in the tutorial it gives me the very same error.

> PHP Warning:  GearmanClient::do(): flush(GEARMAN_COULD_NOT_CONNECT)
>   127.0.0.1:4730 -> libgearman/connection.cc:480 in /root/client.php on
>   line 4

Here's the tutorial i've used: http://gearman.org/index.php?id=getting_started

Can someone help me?

Edit:
Ok. I did the following: "apt-get remove gearman-server" and then "apt-get install gearman-job-server". Now the error is gone. But Another Problem: Both, Worker and Client, are now freezing. Just as they wait for something. Can someone help me?

Comment: Sounds like a connection problem. Is the port correct? Is the service listening on that IP? Is the firewall blocking?

Comment: Well. There's a unix command which lists what program runns on what IP:Port. Can you remember this?

Comment: I'm just using standard connection. localhost shouldn't be blocked. Well and the worker starts without any error, mh

Comment: The server can run fine, but if the client connects to somewhere else where no server runs, this just don't work. Just check to ensure that the basic settings are correct. Especially as you've just installed it. There can be other reasons, but for trouble-shooting, check the basics first. Like if the plug is in when you look for computer problems.

Comment: ok. i just doesn't find any 4730 bindings here. top says gearman is running. 3 times. i'll kill all to see whats happening

Comment: Ok. I did the following: "apt-get remove gearman-server" and then "apt-get install gearman-job-server". Now the error is gone. But Another Problem: Both, Worker and Client, are now freezing. Just as they wait for something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when working quickly through the example.  It sounds like you don't have gearmand running - that's the process that will find available workers to do your job.  Remember there are 3 parts - the client who wants the work done, the worker who will do the work, and the job-server (aka gearmand) who will find an available worker for the client's request.

Answer (score 1):

explicitly call: $worker->addServer("localhost",4730);