# Unable to run "gearman" command line tool with gearman 1.1.6

Tags: distributed-computing, gearman

I am trying to run the example on "http://gearman.org/getting_started" on Ubuntu in VirtualBox environment.

At first I tried to download an old version `0.16` by using `apt-get install gearman-job-server`, `apt-get install gearman-tools` and everything worked well. The server ran in the background, I was able to create 2 workers and verify that I can call them by creating a client.

I decided to download and compile the latest version, `1.1.6`. Now, I am trying to do the same thing with the new version and I am having errors.

I run the server as admin:

```
  sudo gearmand
```

The statement

```
  gearadmin --getpid
```

seems to work - it returns me the process ID of the server. Thus, the server is running, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995202/problem-with-gearman-gearman-could-not-connect) is not relevant.

---

Now, I am adding a worker:

```
 gearman -w -f wc -- wc -l
```

It seems to run.

Nevertheless,

```
gearadmin --workers
```

results in something that probably represents and empty list :

```
33 127.0.0.1 - :
.
```

(In version 0.16, I was able to see 2 lines, the second showing the registered function name.)

---

Attempting to run the client

```
 gearman -f wc < /etc/passwd
```

results in

```
 gearman: gearman_client_run_tasks : flush(GEARMAN_COULD_NOT_CONNECT) localhost:0 -> libgearman/connection.cc:671"
```

This might be the very same problem described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883681/gearman-gives-me-gearman-could-not-connect-it-is-definitely-running) - the port not specified, but I have no idea how to do it through the command line tool.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, It looks like the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883681/gearman-gives-me-gearman-could-not-connect-it-is-definitely-running) was the key to success. Probably, the "getting started" section was not updated for a while. Indeed, one must specify a port explicitly for `gearmand` and `gearman` .

Server:

```
 sudo gearmand -p 5000
```

Worker:

```
 gearman -p 5000 -w -f wc -- wc -l
```

Client:

```
 gearman -p 5000 -f wc < /etc/passwd
```

Comment: I also ran into this when compiling from source. When I install from the repo the need to specify a port went away. I'm wondering if there is an error in configure that sets the default port incorrectly before building or something.